# Android: EditText is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/location_edittext"
    android:id="@+id/locationEditext"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"
    android:hint="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24" />


<com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">
</com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration>

<EditText
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/location_edittext"
    android:id="@+id/locationEditext9"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"
    android:hint="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"/>
```

This is my linear layout, my problem is that last editText is not showing as  my view pager is taking so much space and hiding last edittext I dont know why?

Comment: So the problem in your custom ViewPager, particularly in onMeasure or onLayout methods. You can avoid this problem using relative layout.

Comment: I have tried it but can't reach in correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution of the problem using Relative and Linear Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/location_edittext"
    android:id="@+id/locationEditext"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"
    android:hint="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/locationEditext"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">
</com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration>

<ListView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/shopListview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"` won't work since you are in a `LinearLayout`.

Then, I don't know what `ViewPagerCustomDuration` does, but if you are trying to put the `EditText` at the bottom of the screen, then you should use the weights.

Try to assign `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` the the two `EditText` and for the `ViewPager` use

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Viktor mentioned in his comment, you may just want to use a RelativeLayout. But if you want to use a LinearLayout you can utilize the `"layout_weight"` xml attribute

Set all the `layout_height` attributes to 0dp and use the `layout_weight` as a percentage to specifiy the height each view takes on the screen. For example:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@drawable/location_edittext"
    android:id="@+id/locationEditext"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"
    android:hint="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24" />


<com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">
</com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration>

<EditText
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@drawable/location_edittext"
    android:id="@+id/locationEditext9"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"
    android:hint="Galli No 1, U Block, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24"/>
```

This implementation will have your EditTexts taking up about 20% of the screen each and the custom ViewPager taking up 60%. Change these around as desired.

Comment: weights seems to work perfectly but when I click on edittext my view pager become small why, should I use relative layout, then how?